# Download only the content of a folder from GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm working on a gitlab pipeline that among the other things should work with some file located in another gitlab repo.
For now I do it like this:

```
script:
 - git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${TOKEN}@${repo}.git  
 - cd repository
 - git checkout desired-branch  
 - cd desired/folder  
  #then perform the desired operations like: 
 - ls
```

Also if the previous code works it seems to me a waste of resources to clone every time the whole repo including all the folders, all the commits and all the branches when I'm just interested on a simple folder.
Is there a specific gitlab command that allows me to just download the desired files?
For example:

```
script:
 - git download  https://gitlab-ci-token:${TOKEN}@${repo}.git --f="desired-folder" --b="desired-branch"
 - ls
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+directory

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52269934/7976758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve some of your issues by (a) performing a [shallow clone](https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/#user-content-shallow-clones) and (b) specifying your target branch in the clone command:

```
script:
  - git clone -b desired-branch --depth=1 https://...
```

By using a shallow clone, you are downloading only the HEAD commit and **not** the entire repository history. By using the `-b <branch>` option you're saving yourself from having to run `git checkout desired-branch` after the clone completes.

---

For a project hosted specifically on gitlab, there is generally a direct download link available for any given file. For example, take a look at [this README file](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-docs/-/blob/main/README.md). There is a [direct download link available](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-docs/-/raw/main/README.md?inline=false) available by clicking on the "download" icon on the right.

Using that facility, you could replace your git clone/cd/etc with a single `curl` command if all you need is a single file.